# How to use descriptive programming in RFT?

Tags: rft

I'm new to Rational Functional Tester(RFT). I want to know, How to use decriptive progrmming in RFT? and is it possible to edit scriptname.java file?

What is the equivalent RFT command for QTP's execute command?

Answer (score 2):

1) Regarding descriptive programming, the analogous feature in RFT is the `find` function. See my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071444/how-to-get-rational-functional-tester-to-perform-the-recorded-action-on-every-row) on the subject.

2) Is it possible to edit scriptname.java file? You do not want to muck around with the script files directly, as there are a number of supporting files for each script. If you want to rename a script, use the test explorer pane, right-click the script and select rename.

3) I'm not sure there is a direct analog for this. Here this is really a VBScript command, not QTP. There are many differences between VBScript and Java. VBScript is interpreted, Java is compiled. Is there something in particular that you are trying to accomplish?